# Swift 4 Upgrade cause "use of unresolved identifier" for global variables

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, global-variables, swift4

I have installed Swift 4 and some new amendment needs to be done because a lot of error appears.
I ve mended some issues/warnings, but i m struggling for this one.

I have my GlobalVariables declared in another swift file.

```
class GlobalVariables {
    static var sharedinstance = GlobalVariables()

    var circuitselectionne: String?
    var channeldetelechargement: String?

    private init() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And i use this Global Variable in another view controller like this:

```
print(GlobalVariables.sharedinstance.circuitselectionne!)
```

With Swift 3, everything was ok but now, I've got this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier `GlobalVariables`.

Any idea and the reason of this change?

Comment: Unrelated but you probably should consider declaring your `GlobalVariables.sharedinstance` as a *constant reference* (using `let` and not `var`).

Comment: @hugo75 If the `class GlobalVariables` is different package/module you have to specify as `public` because default all class without specifier declared as `internal` which you can't use outside the package/module.

Comment: @deoKasuhal, i ve tried but no change... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried you code in the test project. It works fine.
You can check it in [link](https://github.com/sergVn/Test-Sharedinstance).

The other idea that you uncheck your file from the target.
[image]

Please check:

[image]

Comment: Classic mistake... I thought it was the Swift 4 upgrade... Thx mate

Answer (score 0):

I had an extension of a class:

```
extension CommandLineApplication: GADInterstitialDelegate {

    /// Set up ads.
    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        ...

        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

and a global variable: `var interstitial: GADInterstitial!`.

I fixed the error putting the name of the module in wich the global variable is declared. My project is named LibTerm so I wrote `LibTerm.interstitial`.